# Windows function that works like: Linux queue_delayed_work( workq, dwork, delay)

Tags: windows, queue, delayed-job, nonblocking

```
Queue_delayed_work is a non blocking "timer" function which will queue `dwork` after `delay` jiffies.
```

I cannot find any non blocking function WIN API, which does same.

Any idea if some function is there, and I don't know. Or How can implement something like this (a non blocking "timer", which will queue `dwork` on `workq`after *at least* `delay` jiffies.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux user space,
Only teo system calls allow setting a timer without simultaneously blocking the calling process on a event:

```
-timer_set_time
-Alarm
```

For Win Kernel,

Can implement with KTIMER

```
KTIMER (Wdm.h)
KeInitializeTimer(PKTIMER Timer):
Timer: Pointer to a timer object, for which the caller provides the storage.
KeSetTimer (PKTIMER Timer, LARGE_INTEGER DueTimer, **PKDPC Dpc**)
```

For Win User space,

Can implement with Waitable Timer Objects:

```
BOOL SetWaitableTimer(
HANDLE hTimer, // handle to a timer object
const LARGE_INTEGER *pDueTime, // when timer will become signaled
LONG lPeriod, // periodic timer interval
PTIMERAPCROUTINE pfnCompletionRoutine, // pointer to the completion routine
LPVOID lpArgToCompletionRoutine, // data passed to the completion routine
BOOL fResume // flag for resume state    
);
```